# Asp.net Core add several action filters in one filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create a custom action filter attribute, that contains in it a declaration of 2 "RouteAttibute" filters.

I need:

```
[Contains2Routes]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Instead of:

```
[Route("~/index1")]
[Route("~/index2")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225901/create-custom-route-attribute-in-asp-net-core-2/53316458#53316458) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin) with his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225901/create-custom-route-attribute-in-asp-net-core-2/53316458#53316458), I've managed to solve this:

```
public class Contains2RoutesAttribute : Attribute, IActionModelConvention
{

    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        action.Selectors.Clear();

        // Adding route 1:
        action.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
        {
            AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel { Template = "~/index1" }
        });

        // Adding route 2:
        action.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
        {
            AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel { Template = "~/index2" }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help. You actually don't need to implement `IResourceFilter` here in your situation, as you're only applying routes.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Great! thanks! I have one problem though, I can't make this attribute work with `IFilterFactory` in order to inject some services I need in this attribute. The `Apply()` method is not being called when the `CreateInstance()` method is in place.

Comment: @KirkLarkin - Posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525645/asp-net-core-custom-filter-implementing-iactionmodelconvention-and-ifilterfactor