# Asp.net Core custom filter implementing IActionModelConvention and IFilterFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, custom-action-filter

I need to create a custom action filter that implements both `IActionModelConvention` and `IFilterFactory`.

I use `IActionModelConvention` for setting several routes at the same time, and I use `IFilterFactory` to inject some services I need to use.

**The problem** is that the `Apply()` method from the `IActionModelConvention` is being called before the `CreateInstance()` method from the `IFilterFactory`, and I need the injected services to be available in the `Apply()`.

**My question** is how do I inject the services before the `Apply()` method is being called? and I also prefer to use `IFilterFactory` to inject services because it doesn't force me to wrap the actual attribute with the `[ServiceFilter]` or `[TypeFilter]` attributes.

Here is my code:

```
public class Contains2RoutesAttribute : Attribute, IActionModelConvention, IFilterFactory
{
    public ISomeService SomeService{ get; set; }

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ISomeService someService = serviceProvider.GetService<ISomeService>();
        return new Contains2RoutesAttribute() { SomeService = someService };
    }

    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        // Here I need to use the service injected:
        this.SomeService.DoSomething(); // ERROR: The service here is null.

        action.Selectors.Clear();

        // Adding route 1:
        action.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
        {
            AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel { Template = "~/index1" }
        });

        // Adding route 2:
        action.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
        {
            AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel { Template = "~/index2" }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Apply` method is just called once for each action at startup, whereas the filter is created for each request. Do you need the `ISomeService` in order to determine the routes that need to be applied or can that just live in its own separate filter attribute?

Comment: @KirkLarkin - Yes, I do need the `ISomeService` in order to determine the routes that need to be applied.

Comment: Does this attribute do anything other than set the routes? It seems like you're trying to set it up as a filter as well but I don't see any filter logic.

Comment: @KirkLarkin - No, it only sets the routes, but I need the `ISomeService` in order to determine the routes to apply.

Comment: Ok. Can you just show how you set up `ISomeService` in `ConfigureServices`? I should have enough information to post an answer then.

Comment: @KirkLarkin - `services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();` Simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IActionModelConvention` implementation will run only once, at startup. `Apply` will be called once for each action. To use `ISomeService` inside of the `Apply` function, pass it through as a constructor argument. Your `Contains2RoutesAttribute` class need not be an attribute or an implementation of `IFilterFactory`, as you've confirmed in the comments that it does not participate in the [filter pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Here's a code example, where I've also renamed the class to better represent what it's doing (it's no longer an attribute):

```
public class Contains2RoutesConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    private readonly ISomeService someService;

    public Contains2RoutesConvention(ISomeService someService)
    {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    public void Apply(ActionModel actionModel)
    {
        someService.DoSomething();

        ...
    }
}
```

Register this convention in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new Contains2RoutesConvention(new SomeService()));
});
```

This is where it gets a bit more interesting. You can't use dependency injection with a [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1#conventions), so in this example, I've created an instance of `SomeService` inline when constructing `Contains2RoutesConvention`. If you want this instance to be a singleton that can be used elsewhere in your application, you can do something like this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
var someService = new SomeService();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new Contains2RoutesConvention(someService));
});

services.AddSingleton<ISomeService>(someService);
```

Of course, this depends on whether or not `SomeService` has dependencies of its own, but if it does, they would not be resolvable from the DI container as it's too early in the pipeline.